# Limit at infinity of polynomial function

Tags: limits, polynomials

My problem is the following.

Let $f(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dots + a_0$ be a polynomial function with $n>0$ and $a_n>0$.  Prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)= \infty$.

My teacher asked me to prove it strictly, that is, using the following definition:

> $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)= \infty$ $\iff$ for every $M>0$, there exists
> $N>0$ ($N$ can usually be denoted by a function of $M$) such that if
> $x>N$ then $f(x)>M$.

After thinking for several days, I can't still prove it using the definition. Precisely, I don't know how to choose the corresponding $N$ to show that $f(x)>M$.

Hope masters are willing to teach me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider that $f(x) > a_nx^n$ when $x > 0.$ Given some $M,$ can you find an $N$ such that $x > N \to a_nx^n > M$? (remember that $x^n$ is monotonically increasing when $x > 0$)

Comment: @StephenDonovan We don't know that the other coefficients are non-negative. So $f(x)>a_nx^n$ is not necessarily true.

Comment: Oh my bad, I read $a_n > 0$ and I thought $a_n$ was the sequence of coefficients, I forgot $n$ was bound. Sorry

Comment: It will be helpful to rewrite the polynomial as $f(x)=a_n x^n(1+\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n} \frac{1}{x}+...)$

Comment: @Paul Yes, but how can I describe the limit of brackets is 1 strictly? I mean if I want to do it, I need to use limit laws, but every term of the polynomial is divergent.

Comment: It's okay now. I've done it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

As often, the simplest  is to use *asymptotic analysis*: factor out $a_nx^n$ to obtain
$$f(x)=a_nx^n\Bigl(1+\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n x}+\dots+\frac{a_0}{a_nx^n}\Bigr),$$
and check the second factor tends to $1$, so that
$$f(x)\sim_\infty a_nx^n.$$

Comment: But how to describe it strictly logical? limit laws can be used only when the limits are convergent. But every term of the polynomial would be divergent.

Comment: It's okay now. I've done it. Thanks

Comment: @Water: to answer your objection (which I discover now), asymptotic equivalence ($\sim_\infty$) is a perfectly rigourous  notion, with the theorem that two asymptotically equivalent functions have the same limit at $\infty$.